# Android: WebView inside of appBarLayout unable to scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-webview

I have an activity which I will show xml for below, containing a webView inside an appBarLayout. Now to be frank, I don't know where the appBarLayout came from because I dont remember adding it in. But anyways, the screen has stacked in the following order top->bottom: a textView, a videoView, and a webView. So the HTML being displayed in the webview is only maybe the bottom half of the screen. Below the xml snippet, I have a image of how this looks from the design POV. The closest I ever got to scrolling is if the webView and friends are **NOT** children of appBarLayout but then the webview takes up entire screen which is not desirable.

I admit, this probably is setup wrong but I will gladly take whatever advice you have and suggestions on editing the way this is arranged/configured.

**Activity XML**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Lesson">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ProjectName.AppBarOverlay"
        android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/reem_kufi"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:text="Title Goes Here"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/lessonContentView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
            android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Kotlin File**

```
class Lesson : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLessonBinding
    private lateinit var webView: WebView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityLessonBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        webView = findViewById(R.id.lessonContentView)
        if(webView != null){
            webView.requestFocus()
            webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            webView.isSoundEffectsEnabled = true
            webView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
            webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
            webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
            webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
            webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                    if (url != null) {
                        view?.loadUrl(url)
                    }
                    return true
                }
            }
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/lesson.html")
        }

        val youTubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView? = findViewById(R.id.videoView)
        if (youTubePlayerView != null) {
            lifecycle.addObserver(youTubePlayerView)
        }
        youTubePlayerView?.addYouTubePlayerListener(object : AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
            override fun onReady(youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer) {
                val videoId = "yJdkdiAly0w"
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, 0F)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_lesson)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

[Component Tree & Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPLVP.png)

[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNNY1.png)

[How it looked when I got it to scroll but not how I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFxBz.png)

I have already tried the advice given on several posts here on StackOverflow so please do not just mark as Duplicate and run off. Probably a quarter of the code in the project right now is from me trying to get scrolling to work with the advice of this site.

I have tried messing with all the scroll attributes for basically every view on here.
I have added StackOverflow recommended items such as the `app:layout_behavior` and these webview settings below:

```
webView.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true
webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
webView.settings.allowContentAccess = true
```

When I got it to scroll but wasnt correct, shown in image link earlier, I had removed all the views from the appBarLayout parent making everything a direct child of what this says is a "CoordinatorLayout".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received help outside of SO (Discord) and I will go over the changes below.

First, I removed the `appBarLayout`. As originally mentioned, I wasn't even sure about it or how it got there as a parent of everything. I also removed ITS PARENT the `coordinatorLayout` by changing it to a `constraintLayout`. This is the parent of my 3 needed pieces (text, video, web) all stacked on top of each other. A few attributes were removed from the xml as well.

Please feel free to comment if you see this in the future and have questions about how I solved this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Lesson">

<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="412dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/reem_kufi"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="Winds &amp; Temperatures Aloft"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/lessonContentView"
        android:layout_width="412dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/videoView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.483"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```